# Neo4j Relationship Index - Search on relationship property

Tags: java, neo4j, bigdata

I've got a neo4j graph with the following structure.

(Account) ---[Transaction]--- (Account)

Transaction is a neo4j relationship and Account is a node.

There are set various properties on each transaction, such as the transaction ID, amount, date, and various other banking information.

I can run a search by Account id, and it returns fine. However when I search by transaction ID, neo4J searches the entire graph instead of using index, and the search fails.

I created indexes using `org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.BatchInserterImpl.createDeferredSchemaIndex()` for both Account.number and Transaction.txid. The index seems to function for Account (node) searches but not for Transaction (relationship) searches. (I have also enabled auto index for node and relationship, but it doesnt change things)

I'm thinking that indexing on relationship properties is not supported, so considering making intermediate nodes to hold property information. However, I'd prefer to stick to my original design if possible.

Any idea how to proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [legacy indexes](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/indexing.html) or [auto indexes](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/auto-indexing.html) to index relationships. Schema indexes do not support indexing relationships.

The reason for that: Typically you use use nodes to model the #things# or #entities# in your domain. Relationship wire up your world and put the nodes into a semantic context. When following that model you typically don't have to index relationships since your queries always start at a #thing# which is always a node.

In your model, you should rethink modelling, I guess it could make sense to have

```
 (account)-[:send]->(transaction)-[:to]->(account).
```

So transactions are a thing on its own and therefore become nodes.

Comment: Hi, that's what I suspected. Just to confirm, it's not supported to query the legacy index from cypher, right?

Comment: for sure you can query a legacy index in cypher using the start clause: for the autoindex use `START r=relationship:relationship_auto_index(key='value') return r`, for a normal legacy index: `start r=relationship:<indexname>(key='value')...`

Comment: I have a relationship with a createdAt field and I just want to know when they were created -- I cant create an index on this? Restructuring the graph seems superfluous

Comment: Is auto indexing supported on neo4j 2.3? Or is it deprecated? The link to the docs is no longer working.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but it look's to me like you're suggesting relationships shouldn't need to have index-able properties.  If so, I'm interested in how you suggest you would approach schema design where say you want to traverse based on the age of the relationship for example.  Where one person (node) has known another for over a variable time period?