# Neo4j Performance

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm executing a simple query in neo4j which is taking around 5s in the first attempt and then around 100ms in next tries. The query is :

```
match (n:user{phone:'224'})-[:knows]->
(m:user{phone:'1234'}) return count(m);
```

**total nodes : 80002 of label user

relationships : around 80 Million nodes**

**Index on :user(phone)**
Query execution plan is also using phone index as its first step. 
Is the data large enough to justify 5s query time or there is some performance tuning which I can use for the server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Neo4j Relationship Index - Search on relationship property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25537885/neo4j-relationship-index-search-on-relationship-property)

Comment: If you add a "isactive" relationship instead of a flag, I expect your query'll run a lot faster.

Comment: Yes, It was a mistake on my part. Query is taking 5s without is_active flag, and around 12 sec with the is_active property. I am editing the question based on that

Comment: How fast is match (n:user{phone:'224'}) WHERE ((n)-[:knows]->
(m:user{phone:'1234'})) return count(m);

Answer (score 2):

I assume your first execution of that query is on a cold cache. Subsequent invocation benefit from accessing nodes and relationships from the cache instead of fetching them form your IO subsystem. For details look at the [reference manual](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/configuration-io-examples.html#_introduction_6).

A common best practice is to warm up caches after server startup.

Comment: I warmed up the cache and now queries are taking around 100ms and that works for me.

Comment: I'm trying to find the execution time of GDS algorithms using the community edition of Neo4j. Is there any way to find it rather than query logging? Since this facility is specific to the enterprise edition @StefanArmbruster